# can an Array be post by ajax?and how?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json, post

the question is like the title,and this some code，and i find all the parameter are post successfully,but i can't see any argument by php's 'echo $_post;'can you help me?
thank you very much!

---

the post url:http://tel.xidian.cc/post.php?action=edit
the result of firebug's post:

```
     depart[] ,birthday,toyou,very,name,mrdoooger,hello
     id[]   ,90,91,92,99,100,101
     sort[] ,1,1,1,1,1,1
     title[]    ,happy,good,nice,my,is,hi`enter code here`

         {`enter code here`for(var i=1;i<n;i++){
         `enter code here`$(".selectlist").find(".edit_"+i).each(function(){
         var input_sort =$(this).find("#edit_1").val();
         var input_123 = $(this).find("#edit_2").val();
         var input_456 = $(this).find("#edit_3").val();
         if(input_123==""){
        jNotify("请输入类别1名称");
        return false;
          }
          if(input_456==""){
        jNotify("请输入类别2名称!");
        return false;
          }

          var str_sort = escape(input_sort);
          var str_123 = escape(input_123);
          var str_456 = escape(input_456);
          var iid = $(this).attr("rel");
          sort[i]=str_sort;
          title[i]=str_123;
          depart[i]=str_456;
          id[i]=iid;
          URL = "post.php?action=edit";
          btn = $(this);        
      });

          }
            Data=Data+"&depart[]="+depart+"&title[]="+title+"&id[]="+id+"&
                sort[]="+sort;
            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:URL,
            data:Data,
            success: function(msg){
               if(msg==1){
                  jSuccess("编辑成功!");
                  //var strs = "<div class='del' title='删除'></div>
                                 <div id='show' title='编辑'></div><div 
                                 class='sort'>"+input_sort+"</div><div 
                                 class='txt1'>"+input_123+"</div>"+"<div 
                                 class='txt2'>"+input_456+"</div>";
                  //btn.parent().html(strs);   
               }else{
                   jNotify("操作失败!");
                   return false;
               }
            }   
    });
```

}

Comment: with serializeArray() refs: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: For arrays, you need to use `print_r($Array);` to ouput the contents. `echo $Array;` will not work.

Comment: `echo $_POST` will only output 'Array'. You need to use `var_dump($_POST)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For arrays you must use:

```
print_r($_POST);
// or
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: thank u very much,i'm a new php developer,and i'm trying print the information i need by "foreach"...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
  $test = array( 'one' => '2', 'three', 4 );
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  var_export($test);
  die();
```

It will return in your firebug console